# Singly linked list program

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

So here I have created a C program to create and display a singly linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    };
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *newnode;
    int choice=1,count=0;
    while(choice==1){
        newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter data");
        scanf("%d",&newnode->data);
        newnode->next=0;
        if(head==0)
        {
            head=temp=newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next=newnode;
            temp=newnode;
        }
        printf("\nDo you want to continue\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
    }
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
        count++;
    }
    getch();
}
```

I'm not getting the desired output i.e. the linked list I am creating is not being displayed. Can someone please help me out and tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: You never update `head`. I think you need to not allocate `head` and `temp`, and just initialize them to 0 (NULL).

Comment: A smaller, more abstract point: develop new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible. Just hard-code a couple of values; don't put user I/O into this program until you have the linked list working perfectly.

Comment: Oh. Thank you  very much!!! I did what you said and my code ran successfully. Also can you please explain why I need not allocate memory to head and temp? I thought one could only use pointers after memory has been allocated to them.

Comment: Pointers need to be initialized or assigned a value — either NULL if there's nowhere for them to point to, or a pointer to some already allocated memory.  You shouldn't attempt to use a pointer until it has been initialized to point somewhere, and you shouldn't dereference a null pointer.  By using `struct node *head = malloc(…);`, you pretty much guarantee that the `if (head == 0)` test will never be true.  But you don't initialize the allocated memory, so all hell is likely to break loose.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your code:

- `head` should not start as a node instance: you don't have any value yet. It should start as `NULL`, which is also in line with the `if` condition you have in the loop. `NULL` represents an empty list, which is what you want to start with. Two problems are the consequence of this:

  - Since it isn't `NULL` at the start, the `(head==0)` condition is never true, and the loop never updates `head`. All the work done remains detached from this `head` node.
  - `head` references a node that is not initialised. Its value is undefined, and worse, its `next` reference is undefined. This leads to undefined behaviour during the print loop, where this `next` reference is used.
- `temp` starts as a node instance, but as in the loop, `temp` is assigned `temp->next`, the code loses a reference to the original `temp` node. And each time `temp` progresses to the next, also the references to all other created nodes are lost.
- `temp` is not a very useful name, as this variable has the same life time as `head`. In practice it represents the *tail* of the list in the first loop, so call it `tail`. The first point holds also for this `tail`: it should start as `NULL`
- `count` is never *used*. Moreover, it should not be incremented during a print-job: that is mixing two jobs. Either count the nodes or print them, but don't do it together. Anyway, as this code has no use for this count, I'd just drop it.
- It is better practice to use `NULL` when related to a pointer data type, not 0.
- Separate functionality: now you have literally *everything* happening in one function: creating nodes, getting input, outputting nodes,... This is not maintainable. Separate different domains of functionality in separate functions.
- If the only reason for include `conio.h` is to make that final `getch` call, presumably because you want to use to press enter at the end of the program, then just leave it out.

Here is some suggested code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Define struct outside of main
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

// Define some functions that perform common actions for a list
struct node *createNode(int data)
{
    struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    // Initialise the struct, so avoiding undefined behaviour
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

struct node *appendNode(struct node *tail, int data) 
{
    struct node *newnode = createNode(data);
    if (tail != NULL) {
        tail->next = newnode;
    }
    return newnode;
}

void printList(struct node *head) 
{
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", head->data); // Space between outputs
        head = head->next; // head is a local variable, so we can change it
    }
    printf("\n");  // Terminate line
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL; // Start with empty list
    struct node *tail = NULL; // Better name. In beginning we don't have a tail
    int choice = 1, data = 0;
    while (choice == 1) {
        // First get the data, and only then create the node
        printf("Enter data: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        tail = appendNode(tail, data);
        if (head == NULL)  // Use NULL constant
        {
            head = tail;
        }
        printf("Do you want to continue? (0=no, 1=yes): ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```